# Graceful stop of arangod on Windows10?

Tags: arangodb

Learning ArangoDB. I have had corrupt databases and had to reinstall arrangodb because it wouldn't start up.  Of course I was not properly shutting down the database, I would close lid and let the PC go to sleep, a little concerning that the database isn't a little more durable. I was using mmfiles, but just changed to dbrocks. hopefully that will help. Using 3.3.11.

1) How do I shutdown the arango server process gracefully in Windows? Didn't see anything in arangod help from the command line. If I stop in the services window, will that properly shut the server down and flush all the data to disk properly?

2) How to I start ArrangDB from the command line too?

Thanks, Mark

Comment: net start arangod and net stop arangod run as an Admin seem to do the trick...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your arangodb database should be fine with sleep / wakeup. It is a different story, when you have hard power off situations. In which case a database repair should fix your startup issues. The arangodb service, if installed as one, is shutdown gracefully, when Windows is shut down.

Do you have log files or your situation or have a database in such a state? We would like to fix it, if it's a bug. Also in case a database does get corrupted

Comment: Alot of this: {startup} startup aborted: caught exception during start of feature 'Database': illegal or unreadable parameter file. shutting down
C:\b\workspace\RELEASE__BuildPackages\lib\ApplicationFeatures\ApplicationServer.cpp
arangodb::application_features::ApplicationServer::start
608 -- don't have old databases.

Comment: @MRB Please report this problem as issue on GitHub: https://github.com/arangodb/planning/issues/new